# How do I install the KDE desktop environment on Ubuntu?

Tags: kde

I am a new user of Linux. I just installed Ubuntu and now I want to try the KDE desktop environment. Can you guide me how to set up KDE in Ubuntu?

Answer (score 3):

To install the KDE Desktop, go to the terminal and type in this command:

```
sudo apt-get install kubuntu-desktop
```

This will install the KDE desktop environment on Ubuntu. Reboot, then select the KDE desktop at the login screen (it will look like something similar to this):

[image: lightdm KDE login]

Enjoy!

Answer (score 1):

You should try Kubuntu for best experience. Kubuntu is optimized for KDE, Ubuntu is optimized for Unity. Installing KDE in Ubuntu will not optimize it in any way.